# In a WEBAPI REST how to use DTO and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, rest, asp.net-web-api, dto

How should the query of several entities or objects be performed, with DTO and LINQ?

I am developing a WEBAPI REST where I have three entities: `Product`, `Category` and `Supplier`.

Each one has its key and the relationship between each of the cases. `Supplier` => `Product` => `Category`

How can I create a query for Product = 'Car', Supplier = 'Ford' and Category = 'Truck' using LINQ which creates a `List<>` that can be returned to the caller --
the `List` data type should be a DTO with the same 3 columns as the filter values (`Product`, `Supplier`, `Category`)?

Please, could you tell me how I should do it, with an example.

Thank you

Comment: "In a WEBAPI REST you should use DTO or LINQ" what? How is a DTO, which is a class that represents a model, comparable to LINQ, an API for working with collections?

Comment: OK, maybe the question is wrong, I need to consume two entities in the same list and show them in a single object

Comment: A typical pattern for your use case might include BOTH the use of **LINQ** for querying the entities and the use of a **DTO** class for returning the results of the query to the caller -- _does this help you understand why your question is confusing, as it is currently worded_?

Comment: Thanks @David, sorry, my English is not good. You have an example where you can use both

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly how to use LINQ in your situation, since the relationship between classes is not very clear, so I'll give you an answer using only the Product object. I can update my answer if you give me more info.

```
var listOfSomethingDto = listOfProducts      //list of products should come from a repository or something similar
    .Where(product => product.Name == "Car") //WHERE:  get products with name equal to what you want
    .Select(product => new SomethingDto      //SELECT: for every product found with the .Where clause
        {                                    //        transform it in a new SomethingDto where the Product is the name of the product found
            Product = productName
        }
).ToList();
```

To filter `Supplier` and `Category` you would need to include them (in a similar fashion to `Product`) in the LINQ query respecting the relationship between classes.

In this example, `SomethingDto` (rename this to fit your scenario) can be defined as:

```
public class SomethingDto
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
}
```

Or, in your case, with all the attributes:

```
public class SomethingDto
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, a DTO is an new kind of object used to transfer data from one point to another without actually using you base classes.